# .NET Webhook sender

Tags: .net, api, webhooks, sender

I'm new to webhooks and I'm trying to figure out how to implement a webhook sender in .Net.

There are very little documentation and example on the sender (a lot on the receiver).

Here's the scenario:

Let's say there's a receiver that provides me with an endpoint (url).

Let's say I don't care about subscription because I only want to notify that particular receiver.

Does this whole "webhook scenario" becomes just a regular HTTP post to the receiver? Even if there was a subscription wouldn't it be just a simple HTTP POST to the receiver ?

If the receiver expose an API with a post endpoint and I make a post to that API can it be called a webhook??

Answer (score 1):

yes, you are correct.
You would do a POST request to the receiver url.
Webhooks are a way to notify the receiver when some event happened on your system.